# iOS 8 UITableViewCell Reorder Control Not Displaying

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, ios8

I recently upgraded my iPhone and Xcode to iOS 8 (from iOS 6) and a UITableView that was previously showing the reorder control on the UITableViewCells (in iOS 6) is no longer showing them until I press the deletion control (red circle) on the left side, at which point the "Delete" button slides over from the right side and the reorder control does appear on that particular UITableViewCell. Below are the relevant methods I am implementing in my UITableViewDataSource. I have set the editing property to YES on the UITableViewController, as well as the UITableView and UITableViewCell in viewDidLoad, but the latter two don't seem to have an effect so I removed them.

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView: (UITableView *) tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ContactsCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.editingAccessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

    //All but the last cell should show the reorder control
    if (indexPath.item < contacts.count)
    {
        cell.textLabel.text = [contacts contactNameAtIndex: indexPath.item];
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize: 18];
        cell.textLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        cell.showsReorderControl = YES;
    }
    else
    {
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Add a contact";
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize: 16];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;
        cell.showsReorderControl = NO;
    }

    return cell;
}

- (BOOL) tableView: (UITableView *) tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) indexPath
{
    return indexPath.item < contacts.count; //All but the last cell can be reordered
}

- (void) tableView: (UITableView *) tableView moveRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) fromIndexPath toIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) toIndexPath
{
    [contacts moveContactAtIndex: fromIndexPath.item ToIndex: toIndexPath.item];
}
```

Thanks,

Vatche

Comment: You have to be in edit mode to see the reorder handles.

Comment: As far as I know, I am in edit mode, otherwise the deletion controls wouldn't show up.

Comment: So, I was able to figure it out. I was originally using the dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier method of the UITableView for both of the cell types I have (Contacts Cell and Add Contact Cell). I had split these up into two separate Cell Identifiers (after posting the original question), but even this didn't solve it. I had to remove the dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier calls altogether and always instantiate a new UITableViewCell and now I always see the reorder control.